# Vue CLI build succeeds but shows blank page - Nginx server

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-cli, ubuntu-server

I am having a problem with getting a Vue app to load via Nginx. Basically, the `npm run build` finishes without any errors but when I go to the root URL the page is blank.

I get the following error, related to `chunk-vendors` and `app`, in dev tools console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

When I click on the related files it shows the html on a single line with a red squiggle line underneath and when I scroll over there is nothing inside the `<div id="app">`.

The build folder path is `/home/ubuntu/apps/client/vue-crm/dist` and my Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /home/ubuntu/apps/client/vue-crm/dist;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name _;
 
  location / {
   root /home/ubuntu/apps/client/vue-crm/dist;
   try_files $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

I have run `sudo nginx -t` which comes back OK. Disclaimer, I am a bit of a newb when it comes to deploying using Vue CLI build and Nginx configuration so I could be missing something obvious.

I am running out of ideas on where the problem is. It seems my app is building fine, I just can't get it to load. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the mode of your Vue router - in `hash` mode it works with no setup, out of the box. In `history` mode you need `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: Thanks so much. Although I got another error after adding the extra `$uri` to the Nginx default file, this suggestion pointed me towards the solution. My Vue app is now loading. You could post it as an answer if you like.